# How to get the response time of file, which is uploaded, processed and available to download?

Tags: performance-testing

We want to know the time taken for the uploaded file to be processed and completed in an web application. The purpose is to get the performance of the application for different file formats and the data loads.

How best can this be achieved using any open source tools.?

Any directions here are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) an open-source load testing framework based on Scala.
You have simple example of the file uploading using gatling [here](http://javamule.blogspot.co.il/).